# Htaccess redirect if no domain at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I can find plenty of solutions forcing e.g. the www domain to be used at all times.
However, I want to create a rule that only forces the www domain when no other domain is present. This is because we have multiple domains that should continue working, e.g. cdn.chainels.com and such. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? So redirecting to the www-domain only if no other (random, I don't want to hardcode this) domain is used (so http://chainels.com redirects to http://www.chainels.com, but http://cdn.chainels.com will be untouched). Thanks!

Edit: and if we're on it, is it also possible to redirect *.nl to *.com at all times, using the same rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I am currently using these three htaccess rules that solve my problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.chainels.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^chainels.(com|nl)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.chainels.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: No. That will redirect for **only** chainels.com or chainels.nl

Comment: Although the rewrite condition should work here, you should get in the habit of always escaping metacharacters in a regular expression pattern: `^chainels\.(com|nl)$` just to be safe.